# Can I pass an array to a function using the ... rest* construction?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm making multiple similar calls with similar results to one remote object. Because these calls are so similar and very changeable, I've been keeping the name of the remote method in a config file, and when I need to make the call I use getOperation() on the remote object, and call send() on the operation object. However, the requirements have changed so that not all of the calls will have the same number of parameters.

Because send uses ..., will I be able to continue using the same formation and pass an array, or will send() treat that as passing one argument of type array?

Comment: as a side-note, and maybe this will help clarify any confusion: if the way you've abstracted your RO's Operation causes issues because your operation.send() call is sending one Array as the sole argument, look into Function.apply().  So, in your example where you want to break apart your array of args into the send() call, you'd do something like:

(operation.send as Function).apply(targetThis, arrayOfArgs).
That would break-up your args if you were finding that you were sending one array object into your remote method signature.

Hope that helps.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Operation class also has an "arguments" property that you can use. That way you can prefill it before calling send(). The send() method then requires not extra arguments.

```
var operation:Operation = Operation(remoteObject.getOperation(methodName));
operation.arguments = parameters;

var token:AsyncToken = operation.send();
var responder:Responder = new Responder(resultHandler, faultHandler);
token.addResponder(responder);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ...rest

that will give you an array with a bunch of objects. I would recommend tat you make the first item `[0]` always the ID. This ID should identify either the sender or the type of object being passed. you can easily do a switch/case for each type of item. You could also do a more sophisticated way of dealing with this, but this should work.